# Replacing Microsoft Word Newline Character in Python

Tags: python, ms-word, sanitize

This feels like it should be an easy one, but I'm having trouble cleaning out the newline character in content pasted from Microsoft Word. Not a full line-break, but the <kbd>CTRL ENTER</kbd> character that shows up as a return arrow in Word. I've tried `chr(10)`, `chr(13)`, `\u000D`, `\u000A` and a few others, but I can't match it in a string.replace(). Should I be looking for a different character or do I need to use something other than the `string.replace` method?

Comment: May be read the text byte by byte and print ordinal of it?
for c in text: print ord(c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this:

```
print repr(mystringobject)
```

That will give a hint of which character you want to remove.

If still no clue, paste the result of the command above in the question, and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks to both you and Chris. It was \x0b

Answer (score 2):

you can get the ASCII value of the character like this:

```
for c in 'string':
    print ord(c), hex(ord(c))
```

once you know the code, it should be easy to kill the offender.